# bourbon sass font-face font location compile error with npm

Tags: npm, webpack, font-face, bourbon

I am using [bourbon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bourbon) and using their [font-face sass function](https://www.bourbon.io/docs/latest/#font-face).

See my sass below.

```
$panton: (

    ("Panton-Light-Italic", 'italic', 300),
    ("Panton-Light", 'normal', 300),

    ("Panton-Regular", 'normal', 400),
    ("Panton-Regular-Italic", 'italic', 400),

    ("Panton-Bold", 'normal', 600),
    ("Panton-Bold-Italic", 'italic', 600),

);

@each $p in $panton {
  @include font-face(
      "Panton",
      "../fonts/panton/#{nth($p,1)}",
          ("woff2", "woff")
  ) {
    font-style: #{nth($p,2)};
    font-weight: #{nth($p,3)};
  }
}
```

But I am having issue compiling and getting this error.

> ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   '../../node_modules/bourbon/core/bourbon/fonts/panton/Panton-Bold-Italic.woff'
>   in '/Users/joshcranwell/Sites/werksmotorsport-v2/src/scss'

For some reason its looking for the fonts inside `bourbon node_modules` folder when actually it's located here...

[image]

This is my `webpack.mix.js` which is working perfectly for font awesome with no addition variable overrides. All my required font awesome fonts get compiled to the distribution as expected.

```
 mix.js('src/js/theme.js', 'dist/js')
    .js('src/js/dashboard.js', 'dist/js')
    .sass('src/scss/screen.scss', 'dist/css')
    .sass('src/scss/dashboard.scss', 'dist/css')
    .setPublicPath('dist')
    .setResourceRoot('../');
```

But some not compiling when using bourbon font-face.

Any help would be awesome.

---

**Update**

If I use `~/../fonts/panton/#{nth($p,1)}` on the url it compiles but doesn't move the fonts to the distribution folder.

Plus the console errors are showing odd locations (no dist folder)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps not quite the answer you're looking for but I suspect this is Bourbon conflicting with Webpack somewhere along the way. It may be more difficult to diagnose than its worth - unless you're heavily using Bourbon throughout your project? I'd say its relatively redundant and you could achieve this with not much more code -

```
$panton: (

    ("Panton-Light-Italic", 'italic', 300),
    ("Panton-Light", 'normal', 300),

    ("Panton-Regular", 'normal', 400),
    ("Panton-Regular-Italic", 'italic', 400),

    ("Panton-Bold", 'normal', 600),
    ("Panton-Bold-Italic", 'italic', 600),

);

@each $p in $panton {
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Panton";
    src: url("../fonts/panton/#{nth($p,1)}.woff2") format('woff2'),
         url("../fonts/panton/#{nth($p,1)}.woff") format('woff'),
    font-style: #{nth($p,2)};
    font-weight: #{nth($p,3)};
  }
}
```

Give that a go perhaps?